# Java - how do I call copy constructor for subclass of subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, copy-constructor

So I have class called 'EducationalBook' that is subclass of class 'Book'. And class 'Book' is the subclass of class 'PaperPublication'.

In my understanding, copy constructor for normal class(like 'PaperPublication') can be written as follow:

```
public class PaperPublication
{
    String title;
    double price;
    int nOP; //number of pages
    public PaperPublication(PaperPublication p)
    {
        title = p.title;
        price = p.price;
        nOP = p.nOP;
    }...
```

However, I am not sure how to build a copy constructor for a subclass with parameter of that class itself only(for example: 'Book' class with parameter (Book b) ONLY). The reason why I want only one parameter is because there's a rule that for copy constructor of subclass, I have to call parent class's copy constructor(I believe this means use "super()" right?). After some research, though I did not find a clear answer, I built as such:

```
public class Book extends PaperPublication
{
    long ISBN;
    int issued;
    String author;
    public Book(Book b)
    {
        super(b.getTitle(), b.getPrice(), b.getNOP());
        ISBN = b.ISBN;
        issued = b.issued;
        author = b.author;
    }...
```

I am not even sure this is correct way to do it, but it at least compiled without occurring any compile-stage error.

However, for EducationalBook class, I don't have any single idea to build a copy constructor. Since Java does not allow something like super.super(), and I am not allowed to utilize parametrized constructor, but only copy constructor of parent class.

```
public class EducationalBook extends Book
{
    int edition;
    String speciality;
    public EducationalBook(EducationalBook e)
    {
        //??? no clue..
    }
    public EducationalBook() // default constructor. is this right?
    {super();}
}
```

(And for additional question, is that default constructor right?)

I feel like my understanding of inheritance of Java is weak overall. Any enlightenment for me?

Comment: It would be `super(b)`, not `super(b.getTitle(), b.getPrice(), b.getNOP());`. You can only call the super constructor that actually exists

Comment: This is very basic concept of java, i suggest you to go through some books or tutorials and give some time in learning.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for pointing that out. FYI I did not write all constructors for PaperPublication Class. Actually all 3 classes mentioned in this question has 3 constructors each: parametrized, copy, and default. But I just tried super(b) and it did compile.. does this do same as [super(b.getTitle(), b.getPrice(), b.getNOP())]?

Comment: How should we know when we don't see those constructors? But as for myself, I'd keep it simple. Have the child copy constructors call the parent's super copy constructor. Why make it difficult on yourself?

Comment: @Dev911 Apologies for elementary-level question. Agree on you totally, I do need some time to spend actually learning Java concepts thoroughly. In actual programming though, I will not bother using "Only one parameter for any copy constructor," as I can easily go around it by utilizing parametrized constructor of parent class.. This "must utilize parent class's copy constructor" drives me to void.

Comment: @jeispyun That's alright , Hope you are clear now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier than you think.

The copy constructor of `Book`:

```
public Book(Book b)
{
  super(b);
  ISBN = b.ISBN;
  issued = b.issued;
  author = b.author;
}
```

And the copy constructor of `EducationalBook`:

```
public EducationalBook(EducationalBook b)
{
  super(b);
  edition = b.edition;
  speciality = b.speciality;
}
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Thank you! Somehow thought Book object cannot go into parent class's copy constructor parameter. Shame on me, must've confused the other way around..